# PHP creating and merging multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having some troubles creating and merging multidimensional arrays.
Trying to explain, I have a dynamic "pack of 4 inputs". Those are generated via PHP and the user can add more "4 packs" of inputs.

Those inputs are named as `input1[en]` or `input1[pt]`.
So, to better understand a simple `$_POST` of `input1`, it prints the following array (still out input2,3 and 4) that needs separated foreach:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [0] => [C][C]
    [1] => [L][L][C]
)
[pt] => Array(
    [0] => [C][C]
)
)
```

Now, I need to create just one array that contains all the information from inputs, but I'm having some trouble right in the first array creation (from input1).

Using the code:

```
foreach($_POST['input1'] as $language => $index){
    foreach($index as $newvalue => $index2){
        $cernegy[$language] = array(
            'energy' => array($newvalue => $index2)                 
        );
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [1] => [L][L][C]
    )
) [pt] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
    )
)
)
```

As you can see it misses the key [0] inside [en].
All the same happens with the others inputs (it only left in the array the last key when there are multiple inputs for the same language (in this case [en]))

My others foreach are equal, but changes the `'energy' => array($newvalue => $index2)` to `'attack' => array($newvalue => $index2)` and so on...

Then, the second problem is merging the arrays. If I merge two arrays (even with wrong information), it only keeps the last merged array.
Basically if I merge `array1` (that generates `'energy'` with `array2` (that generates `'attack'` ) it only keeps the information from from `array2` for example:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [1] => RazorLeaf
    )
) 
[pt] => Array(
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Pontapé
    )
)
)
```

And it should be something like:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [1] => [L][L][C]
    )
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [1] => RazorLeaf
    )
) 
[pt] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
    )
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Pontapé
    )
)
)
```

I've used this to merge (the array names are example only):

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction in both problems please?
Thanks for your time.

**Edit:** First part is now solved. The problem remains now in merging two arrays.
As an example of two arrays ($array1 and $array2 in order):
Array1

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
        [1] => [L][L][C]
    )
) 
[pt] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
    )
)
)
```

Array2

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Tackle
        [1] => RazorLeaf
    )
) 
[pt] => Array(
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Pontapé
    )
)
)
```

As I use `$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);` I was expecting to get:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
        [1] => [L][L][C]
    )
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Tackle
        [1] => RazorLeaf
    )
) 
[pt] => Array(
    [energy] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
    )
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Pontapé
    )
)
)
```

But I only get as output the `$array2` information:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Tackle
        [1] => RazorLeaf
    )
) 
[pt] => Array(
    [attack_name] => Array(
        [0] => Pontapé
    )
)
)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried: `$cernegy[$language][] = ['energy' => [$newvalue => $index2]]` ?

Comment: Or `$cernegy[$language]['energy'][] = [$newvalue => $index2]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly your code seems to create the array with all data, but I don't know if it's the best way to create it. Can you check it please? It seems there is more keys than necessary. `Array(
 [en] => Array(
  [energy] => Array(
   [0] => Array(
    [0] => [C][C]
   ) [1] => Array(
    [1] => [L][L][C]
   )
  )
 ) [pt] => Array(
  [energy] => Array(
   [0] => Array(
    [0] => [C][C]
   )
  )
 )`

Comment: Also the merge still get's the last array only, not merging both.

Comment: @smoqadam your approach works too, but I prefer the logistic of RiggsFolly Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Can you show a `var_export($_POST)` so we can see the original data that we are dealing with please. Edit that into your answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly The information is seriously so much, so it's not a good idea. The first part is solved. I've edited the main code to show the second part of problem with array_merge. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You only have to show us a representative sample, not the whole array

Comment: I've done it. Instead of using `array_merge` used `array_merge_recursive` and it worked. Now I have all the information together. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the value rather than adding to the array. Try something like:

```
foreach($_POST['input1'] as $language => $index){
    $inner = array();
    foreach($index as $newvalue => $index2){
        $inner[$newvalue] = $index2;
     }
     $cernegy[$language] = array('energy' => $inner);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it creates new key where it doesnt exists. Por example I have only one key in `[pt]` and it creates two keys: `Array(
 [en] => Array(
  [energy] => Array(
   [0] => [C][C][1] => [L][L][C]
  )
 ) [pt] => Array(
  [energy] => Array(
   [0] => [C][C][1] => [L][L][C]
  )
 )
)
`

Comment: @Tiago See the edit, I missed out on wiping out the array once done

Comment: thanks. It solved my first problem. I've edited the code with the second problem (arra_merge). Can you check it please?

Comment: I've done it. Instead of using `array_merge` used `array_merge_recursive` and it worked. Now I have all the information together. Thanks for your time!